# Changing backslash to forward slash in a QString

Tags: c++

I have a program that gives a QString and changes every "\" to "/". It seems very simple but when I use the below code, 5 errors happen:

```
QString path ;
path = "C:\MyLife\Image Collection" ;
for( int i=0 ; i < path.size() ; i++ )
{
    if( path[i] == "\" )
        path[i] = "/" ;
}
qDebug() << path ;
```

Comment: "5 errors happen..." Please provide detail about those errors.

Comment: please do not unnecessarily include C tag.

Comment: For one thing " denotes a string in C/C++ - use ' for characters.

Comment: you should have a look at QString::replace and QDir::toNativeSeparators

Comment: You should really accept some anwsers and write better questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  It has come to our attention that you have provided few answers, have accepted no answers, and have not thanked users who have helped you by upvoting their answers. You also do not [pay it forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward) by occasionally trying to help other community members get answers to their questions, too.  If this behavior becomes a pattern, your account may be suspended.  Please realize people are trying to help you, and be considerate of their efforts.

Comment: Just get in the habit of using `/` in paths for Qt, it works on every platform, the `\` is just windows I think, MS and their incompatibility urges...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please, Stop the bleeding, now ! And use a cross-platform directory/path wrapper class. Qt have some : QDir, QFileInfo, QFile. Just use them.

ooh, and QDir have a nice static method for you, which does exactly what you want :

```
 path = QDir::fromNativeSeparators(path);
```

No excuse to do it manually (with bugs)

Comment: same here, is doc incorrect ? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#fromNativeSeparators

Comment: doc is correct. this function does nothing with backslashes on linux, which is correct, since '\' is a valid character for file name and in general such function may make such files inaccessible.

Comment: Unfortunately no: fromNativeSeparators converts \ to / only if the executable is run in windows. If you run it in Linux and need to convert a Windows path, it wont work. (because \ is not native). I found no solutions for that in in Qt.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape \

```
if( path[i] == '\\' )
```

Same with

```
path = "C:\\MyLife\\Image Collection" ;
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Backslash_escapes

Comment: Or use C++0x raw strings! (no escaping required)

Answer (score 3):

Because the backslash `\` is used as an escape character (for things like `\n` newline, `\r` carriage return, and `\b` backspace), you need to escape the backslash with another backslash to give you a literal backslash. That is, wherever you want a `\`, you put `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

> - Strings cannot be compared directly in C/C++.
> - Characters can be compared.
> - "\" is string, whereas '\' is a character.

Comment: You mean: "\\" is a string, whereas '\\' is a character.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has fixed both your errors in the same post, so here goes:

```
    if( path[i] == '\\' ) // Double backslash required, and
        path[i] = '/' ;   // single quote (both times!)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does work for me for *Qt4* on *Linux* is using:

```
std::replace( path.begin(), path.end(), QChar('\\'), QChar('/') );
```

None of the Qt functions work, obviously.